# static_assert : a certain function in Derive "must" hides Base's class function

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, c++17, static-assert

I face a strange rare problem that I want to hide a Base class's function `B::f1(int)`.

```
class B{
    public: void f1(int){}
    public: void f1(float){}
};
class C : public B{
    public: void f1(int){
        //static_assert(ASSERT_that_thisFunctionHidParentFunction,"");
        //some rare ugly hacky stuff
    }
    public: void f1(char){
        //static_assert(!ASSERT_that_thisFunctionHidParentFunction,"");
    }
};
```

Everything works fine ; I just worry about maintainability.
I wish to make sure that a function `C::f1(int)` always hides `B::f1(int)`.

If `B::f1(int)` happen to change signature in the future (e.g. to `B::f1(int,int)`),
 I want some compile error to notify programmers that `C::f1(int)` should be changed to `C::f1(int,int)` as well.

In real world, my problematic function `f1` doesn't have overload.
But for educational purpose, I wish to know how to solve it if there are overload too.  (i.e. optional)

I love a cute solution like `ASSERT_that_thisFunctionHidParentFunction` in my code comment.
I don't mind MACRO.

### My poor solution

I tried to typedef to force compile error, but it doesn't assert-fail in some case ([MCVE-coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff7470bc2428de56)), because `int` is automatically casted to `B::f1(float)`.

```
class B{
    public: void f1(int,int){}
    public: void f1(float){}
};
class C : public B{
    public: void f1(int){
        using XXX=decltype(std::declval<B>().f1(std::declval<int>()));
        //static_assert(ASSERT_that_thisFunctionHidParentFunction,"");
    }
    public: void f1(char){
        //static_assert(!ASSERT_that_thisFunctionHidParentFunction,"");
    }
};
int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Such check would be easy if your functions were `virtual`, see `override` specifier. What real problem do you try to solve? Do you really need to inherit to an implementation (non-interface) class and override a non-virtual method?

Comment: As for your attempted solution, you may find `<boost/tti/has_member_function.hpp>` useful (yet complicated).

Comment: @Igor G :  I has a base class `Ship` that has function `PhysicBody* Ship::createPhysicBody()`.  I have `BattleShip` that inherit from `Ship`.   I want `BattleShip::createPhysicBody()` to do something a little different from the parent class.    ... Thank for the override keyword (my bad, I totally forgot about it), but I don't want to make it virtual yet.

Comment: @Igor G : Thank for `<boost/tti/has_member_function.hpp>`.  It interests me.  :)

Comment: if `f1` is not template, detecting presence and signature of `&B::f1` should do the job.
These is also [`std::experimental::is_detected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Answer (score 1):

You could check that the function pointers are different.

With MSVC 2019 and Clang 8 this worked for me, however GCC rejected it as "not a constant expression", so might need something different or a a runtime assert there. Not sure which is right in regards to the standard.

```
class B {
public:
    void f1(int) {}
    void f2(int) {}
    void f3(int) {}
    void f1(float) {}
};
class C : public B {
public:
    void f1(int) {}
    void f1(char) {}
    void f3(int) {}
};
static_assert(&B::f1 != &C::f1); // Won't work because of the overloading, can static_cast to get the overload you want
static_assert(static_cast<void(B:: *)(int)>(&B::f1) != static_cast<void(C:: *)(int)>(&C::f1));
static_assert(static_cast<void(B:: *)(int)>(&B::f2) != static_cast<void(C:: *)(int)>(&C::f2)); // static assertion failed
static_assert(&B::f3 != &C::f3); // passes, no static_cast as not overloaded
```

Be very careful with hiding a member function in this way, as the base class is public and the method is not virtual. It can easily be cast and then the derived function is not called.

```
C *c = ...;
B *b = c; // Implicit
b->f1(5); // Calls B::f1, not C::f1
```

If possible it may be best to make the inheritance `protected` or `private` to avoid accidental casting.

Comment: `B::f1` is not static function (sad face - like you already mentioned): [MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/859141aec6347d76).

Comment: @javaLover Yes, as I said GCC specifically didn't like it, but not sure which compiler is right/wrong. An `assert` would work, but would only trigger at runtime (for example in a static initialiser or something else very early in the program).

Comment: Thank.   I may try to verify which one is wrong later ... For now, I almost like your answer. XD

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question, it seems that you want to make sure that several implementation classes comply with a certain non-virtual concept.

```
template <typename Candidate>
struct ShipConcept
{
    constexpr ShipConcept()
    {
        using ProtoFoo = void (Candidate::*)(int);
        (void)static_cast<ProtoFoo>(&Candidate::foo);

        // Other tests ...
    }
};


struct Ship_A
 : private ShipConcept<Ship_A>
{
    Ship_A()
    {
    }

    void foo(int, int);
    void foo(float);
    void foo(int);        // (1)
};
```

You'll get compile-time error if line (1) isn't there.